# how to open javascript code after website load

Tags: web, chat, loading, zendesk

my website loading time is too much for zendesk chat, when i remove zendesk chat the website loading time under 2 seconds
here is my zendesk code

```
<script>
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s= d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set._.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");$.src="//v2.zopim.com/?14mOH4BM2323DFADFSAS";z.t=+new Date;$.type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you find that zendesk code, was it inside `<script></script>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

To combat this, a common practice is putting your scripts at the bottom of your body, so that the visual aspects of the website load first before the scripts.

For example:

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <h1>My Website Contents</h1>
      
      <script>console.log('My scripts go down here');</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no that is not working with your example i need to load chat after complete webpage load